# Can't find permalinks section under "Settings"?

Tags: permalinks

I just signed up for a free account. I found a few tutorials on how to set the permalinks but I don't see that under my own dashboard:

[image]

I need to turn on Pretty Permalinks so that I can visit `/wp-json/` to use the API. Can someone tell me where this section is?

Comment: You have a WordPress.com account, which is not the same thing as the self-hosted version of WordPress.

Comment: O... are they both created the same way? I was under the impression that I would just go to wordpress.com and create an account

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress.com is a hosted installation of Wordpress and doesn't allow you to edit things such as permalink structure, or any code other than css.

Sounds like you need to get a Wordpress install running on another server,
Here's a how-to
https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress
then you'll have access to edit your permalinks, .htaccess file etc.

Comment: sorry, but unless you work for a8c it is unlikely that you know what is possible and impossible to get on their sites if you pay enough money

Answer (score 0):

`wp-json` is available by default since version 4.4 (which was released so long ago it is unlikely there are many wordpress sites in the wild which use older versions), and there is no need to turn anything "on" to use it.

You might have some difficulty if pretty permanlink is not used in which case you should consult the wordpress rest API guide on the proper url parameter structure that is needed to emulate the same API endpoints as those you want to use, but again it is very unlikely IMHO to find such configurations in the wild.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it's possible to do what I want using just the hosted solution of Wordpress: 
https://developer.wordpress.com/2016/11/11/wordpress-rest-api-on-wordpress-com/

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/console/

Comment: that doesn't actually answer  your own question :(